# How to save a character with a line above (like this ō) in a file system?

Tags: format

What file format should I use? It is for PHP to afterwards retrieve such a character and for HTML to display.

Comment: Are you trying to create a file with this character in the name or to save the character in the content of the file (such as a text file)? What file system?

Comment: As indicated in reply of quasi-same question, closed a few minutes ago, this is not so much a matter of file format than one of character encoding.  Also, the encoding used when saving must match the encoding used for display purposes.

Comment: I'd like to learn about how both to create a file with this character in the name and to save the character in the content of the file. Also both, ways for Windows and Linux.

Comment: mjv, can't these characters be coped from a web page and pasted in a plain .txt file?

Comment: @Coder123 Define "plain text file". The common [but obsolecent?] understanding of such a file was one where each character is saved as one and only one byte in the file, an read in like fashion, to be used in the context of an implicit codepage.  In that sense, probably not.  Now, if you understand a plain text file, as one that contains characters encoded in say utf-8 (which btw, mostly maps to 1 byte characters for most characters found in European languages), and which is then interpreted by an application that understands utf-8, then in such a file, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be encoding the text as UTF8, then writing it to the file.

If you're doing this with PHP, then (I think) it'll be something like:

```
$f = fopen("/path/to/file", "w");
fwrite($f, utf8_encode($some_string));
fclose($f);
```

(although, this assumes that PHP is using Unicode internally… But, then, it might not – my memory is kind of hazy)

Comment: The implicit input to PHP's utf8_encode() is an `ISO-8859-1` string, and this would therefore not answer Coder123's question, one of the reasons being (not the only one) that 8859-1 does not include any o-with-a-bar looking character.